# Polymer 2 - Paper-Input Prefix not showing

Tags: polymer, prefix

I'm having issues with this paper-input that validates phone numbers.
I want to add the country code as prefix, but it doesn't show.

```html
<paper-input value="{{cellno}}" style="color:white;" label="Ingrese su número de celular" auto-validate pattern="(?:11|[2368]\d)(?:(?=\d{0,2}15)\d{2})??\d{8}$" error-message="Ingrese un número de celular válido" invalid={{invalidCellno}}>
  <div slot="prefix" style="color:white;">+54</div>
</paper-input>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use a div. try with span.

try with

```
<paper-input value="{{cellno}}" style="color:white;" label="Ingrese su número de celular" auto-validate pattern="(?:11|[2368]\d)(?:(?=\d{0,2}15)\d{2})??\d{8}$" error-message="Ingrese un número de celular válido" invalid={{invalidCellno}}>
  <span slot="prefix" style="color:#8e8e8e;">+54</span>
</paper-input>
```

Comment: Perfecto! saludos hasta argentina jaja